# Don't understand signal

Tags: c, signals

Could someone tell me what this line does:

```
if(signal(SIGUSR1, handler) == (sighandler_t)-1)
```

It is a line I copied from an exercise, which made it work, but I don't really understand it. Could someone explain this to me? (It is actually the second part I don't understand: what is the value of (sighandler_t)-1?)

Thank you :)

edit: the sighandler_t comes from

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

Comment: `(sighandler_t)-1` is the minus one digit, cast into `sighandler_t` type. must check to see if the signal call has failed.

Comment: Okay now I got it thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is a bad style and probably non-portable code, `(sighandler_t)-1` should be replaced with one of the predefined signal dispositions. On my system they are declared in next way

```
/* Fake signal functions.  */
#define SIG_ERR ((__sighandler_t) -1)       /* Error return.  */
#define SIG_DFL ((__sighandler_t) 0)        /* Default action.  */
#define SIG_IGN ((__sighandler_t) 1)        /* Ignore signal.  */
```

Other systems may use another values, so assuming that your uses the same definitions, we get next code:

```
if(signal(SIGUSR1, handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    /* got problem */
} else {
   /* handler installed */
}
```

This code installs function `handler` as handler for signal `SIGUSR1` and checks returned value to ensure that it was done successfully. `handler` must be declared as `void handler(int signo);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Are they declared by default or do I have to declare it myself?

Comment: @ArnaudRochez It is a standard declarations, just include `signal.h`.

Answer (score 0):

`(sighandler_t)-1` is the minus one digit, cast it into `sighandler_t` type. You must check to see if the signal call has failed.